# Have there been precedents of presidential campaigns communicating with foreign governments during the election campaign?

Tags: united-states, presidential-election, campaigning

It's [reported this week](http://www.cnn.com/2017/02/14/politics/donald-trump-aides-russians-campaign/index.html) that "Trump aides were in constant touch with senior Russian officials during [the presidential] campaign".

In the CNN article linked above, it states that it's not unusual for a campaign staff and representatives to communicate with foreign governments.

> Officials **emphasized that communications between campaign staff and representatives of foreign governments are not unusual**. However, these communications stood out to investigators due to the frequency and the level of the Trump advisers involved. Investigators have not reached a judgment on the intent of those conversations.
>
> *(emphasis mine)*

So, is this unusual? Have there been precedents of other campaigns in the past that communicated with foreign governments **during the election campaign**?

**Non-opinionated answers with sources are appreciated.**

Comment: Keep reading the text of the Logan act, it specifies criteria for intent. It is not inherently illegal for a private citizen to talk with foreign government officials (otherwise even news interviews would be banned). That also why campaigns in general have some leeway.

Comment: Also worth noting that based on these criteria it is also not clear at all if Flynn actually violated the Logan act (though obviously the lying was still a big problem).

Comment: I know you say it in the question, but I suggest emphasizing that you're asking about *during the campaign* and not after the election.

Comment: @DavidGrinberg Thanks for your comments, I've decided to remove the question since it's a sub-question. I've reread the text of the Logan act and it does seem logical that even news organisations will be banned with my previous interpretation.

Comment: @Bobson Yup, I've placed emphasis on the text *during the campaign*, thanks!

Comment: An interesting dilemma: Obama was clearly a big part of Hillary's campaign. He clearly had contacts with foreign leaders, if nothing else as part of his job.

Comment: @user4012 Obama is an officer of the government though. The logan act does not apply to him.

Comment: @DavidGrinberg - correct. But that's a technicality, as far as the spirit of the question is concerned - it didn't even mention Logan act.

Comment: @user4012 It did in the initial revision.

Comment: Its vague and non specific and overly generalized.  The claim is not refutable because it does not make any substantial assertion.  Say your you have a business dealing with an immigrant from russia.  It could be completely above board and not even about the campaign but it would fit this claim.

Comment: I presume you are asking for examples of *precidents.*

Comment: @user4012: What you say about Obama is a clear intentional misunderstanding / misinterpretation. Logan act isn't against individuals being on some election team, it is about individuals that are not part of the government. Obama was part of the government (actual, the president). Flynn, or Trump before officially becoming president, or Hilary Clinton at any time, not fine.

Comment: @gnasher729 - in a technical legal sense you're correct. In the spirit of the things, Obama was acting a lot as a Clinton campaign surrogate; and it's impossible to tell if he was doing something or other due to that intent.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Probably the most clear example is when a candidate travels to another country and speaks with the head of state. For example Ted Cruz traveled to [Israel and Eastern Europe](https://www.cruz.senate.gov/?p=news&id=1309) for his 2016 campaign. That involved of course Cruz, but also many supporting staff, not all of whom where official government officers. It's pretty common for presidential candidates to have foreign tours during their candidacy, so this happens a fair amount.

Answer (score 4):

Richard Nixon secretly communicated with South Vietnam, asking them to delay peace talks.  LBJ knew about it, and though Nixon denied it, one of his biographers discovered the evidence that he did know:
https://www.politico.com/magazine/story/2017/08/06/nixon-vietnam-candidate-conspired-with-foreign-power-win-election-215461
also *Richard Nixon, The Life*, p 342